# How to change app between dark mode and light mode depending on the time of day?

Tags: java, android

Apparently you can use this:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_TIME);
```

But `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_TIME` is depreciated.

> Automatic switching of dark/light based on the current time is deprecated. Considering using an explicit setting, or MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY.

For what possible reason could such an amazing function be depreciated? And what is the alternative "explicit setting" they talk about?

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the guidelines for supporting dark mode you do not need to worry about if/when its dark/light mode.

The user can setup schedules for if/when the device switches between modes and then app themes will adapt accordingly hence there is no need for that anymore

Comment: Isn't that only applicable to Android 10?

Comment: the automatic switching of themes based on the mode? yes, You can surround that call with a version check for older versions if you need

Comment: I want the theme applicable regardless of Android version

Comment: there is no such thing as dark mode in older versions, you will have to manually create a light and dark theme then manually switch between them in all your activities with an app setting or something

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's better to follow the system settings. If the system is using dark mode, you app will automatically switch to dark mode since most devices support schedule dark mode. If you want your app to switch with time, I guess you have to do it manually like check the time before initializing your views and decide whether to use dark mode or light mode.

Comment: Yes but system dark mode is only available on Android 10 devices. I want it available on all devices.